# Filtering Sequential Date for Subscription Data

Tags: mysql, filter

My data:

| rows | id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01-01-2018 | 01-01-2019 |
| 2 | 1 | 02-02-2018 | 02-02-2019 |
| 3 | 1 | 27-01-2019 | 15-04-2019 |
| 4 | 1 | 22-04-2018 | 21-09-2018 |
| 5 | 1 | 17-04-2019 | 18-12-2019 |
| 6 | 1 | 12-12-2018 | 04-04-2019 |
| 7 | 1 | 03-06-2018 | 06-09-2018 |

Expected value:

| rows | id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01-01-2018 | 01-01-2019 |
| 3 | 1 | 27-01-2019 | 15-04-2019 |
| 5 | 1 | 17-04-2019 | 18-12-2019 |

- the data starts from the oldest with [dd-mm-yyyy]
- I can't create new table to process the date

Question:

1. How to filter the data based on the date if the [start_date] of the next row in the same [id] starts after the [end_date]?

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to turn your strings into dates and then use [`LEAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) to get `start_date` of the next row.

Comment: I would recommend to store dates in ISO format, i.e. yyyy-mm-dd or as native type `DATE`. This way, filtering and sorting is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

For every row find the row with the next highest start-date then union

```
with cte as
(select *, 
      (select rn from t t1 where t1.rn > t.rn and t1.start_date > t.end_date order by t1.rn limit 1) nextrn 
from t)
select * from cte where rn = 1
union all
select * from cte where rn in(select distinct nextrn from cte);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/Uw0LvO69